# Rails "try" a constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization

I am loading serializers by building the namespace and name of them and using `constantize`.

If the serializer doesn't exist then this will throw the **uninitialized constant** error.

Is there any way I can *try* the constant or actively check that the serializer exists before converting the name to a constant?

Comment: How do you deal with missing serializers? Raising a `NameError` doesn't look too bad.

Comment: In my case, I just default to the `ActiveRecord::DefaultSerializer`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Object.const_defined?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_defined%3F):

```
'Serializer'.constantize if Object.const_defined?('Serializer')
```

Alternatively you can also use the Ruby method [`Object.const_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_get) instead the Rails one:

```
Object.const_get('Serializer')
```

Comment: Thanks. While both answers were great, I decided to go with this one to keep it more inline. Will mark as answer when I can.

Comment: This answer does not plays with autoloading well.
`> Object.const_defined?  ('ReportExporters::Summary::CsvExporter')
=> false` but class does exists `> ReportExporters::Summary::CsvExporter
=> ReportExporters::Summary::CsvExporter`

Comment: And with upd: `> Object.const_get('ReportExporters::Summary::CsvExporterSmthn') 
NameError: uninitialized constant ReportExporters::Summary::CsvExporterSmthn
from (pry):14:in `const_get'`

Answer (score 1):

You can handle that exception in that place with `begin..rescue` construction.

Comment: Do not handle exceptions if you can avoid them.

Comment: @RafaPaez yes, of course. But otherwize you will not trigger the Rails autoloading in case, when class is not loaded yet, but still exists.

Comment: I think autoloading it's a different problem and should be resolved beforehand. Thanks for your comments @Ivan

Answer (score -1):

You simply checked it with 'defined? CONST_NAME'.